# How will i do a data search between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to search for rows with a date between two values:

```
select battery_volts
from ems
where date between 20180606 and 20180606
```

Error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: What is the problem your facing with this code ?

Comment: `date` is of type `date` in your DB when `20180606` is an `int`, so you will need to cast one of them to the other type.

Comment: Your dates have to be inside quotation marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote your dates using a single quotation (`'`):

```
SELECT battery_volts
FROM ems
WHERE date BETWEEN '20180606' AND '20180606';
```

Comment: And how can i make sqlserver show me the date and data type that was search not only display the data type.

Comment: @JPPentz what? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with `between`, i would use instead :

```
select battery_volts
from ems
where date >= '20180606' and date < '20180607';
```

Here is a [great article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) that expands on the cautionof using *between*.

Comment: Here is a great article that expands on the caution here of using between. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Way will you say be careful with between Yogesh

Comment: @JPPentz. . . That link (see bottom of my answer) will explain you why ?

Answer (score 1):

If the data type is `date` then you can do

```
select battery_volts
from ems
where date between '2018-06-06' and '2018-06-07'
```

Comment: Yes Juergen the data Type is date